# .htaccess 301 redirect. Redirect from one domain to another

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to ask, how do I redirect from this url(for example): http://firstapp.com/VD/Controller/Action
(VD - is virtual directory, Action - there are many actions, so all of them should be redirected to the new url)

to this one: http://secondapp.com/Action  ?

Using .htaccess

I try this, but it does not work

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/VD/Controller/(.*)$ http://secondapp.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

Comment: Step 1: You do your own _research_. Step 2: You tell us what you have tried, and what problems you ran into while doing so. (Step 0: You read [ask].)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place this rule in root .htaccess of `firstapp.com`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} firstapp\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^VD/Controller/(.*)$ http://secondapp.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```